# Problem with IDA in LoadlibraryA()

Tags: ida-plugin

I am trying to disassemble an online game Client to get something , There is LoadlibraryA() function that call dll file , But that dll file is protected somehow so it show a message that there is a debugger injected in the program and close the Client (Message appear too when trying to use this function and dll in VS C# program debug mode) , So is there any way to try to trace the Client without this message like a stealth program or something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anti-debug techniques for MS-Windows?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/anti-debug-techniques-for-ms-windows)

Comment: what protection is it using? (as that information is kinda critical)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try use a special plugins for IDA which hide debugger from detect.

[ScyllaHide](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3597)

[TitanHide](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3575) (driver)

Comment: Not working give me same message or maybe I am doing something wrong , Do you have tutorials?

Comment: I try ScyllaHide copy all files in plugins in IDA -> Plugins and start IDA then try to analyze get same msg
I am trying to trace SRO_Client Hackshield maybe "ehsvc.dll" need another stealth program?

Comment: Do you sure what ScyllaHide load? Did you look ScyllaHide banner in "Output window" when plugin load? Try copy `scylla_hide.ini` and `NtApiCollection.ini` in  IDA plugin dir too.Check plugin - pres Alt-X and play with configs.